# How to iterate through NodeList and update only for child nodes in Java?

Tags: java, xml, dom

A bit new to xml parsing in java, so I am trying to update certain elements within xml document but I am having some issues updating the correct ones.

```
<Transactions>
    <Transaction>
        <id>222</id>
        <time>...</time>
        <date>...</date>
    </Transaction>
    <Transaction>
        <id>333</id>
        <time>...</time>
        <date>...</date>
    </Transaction>
</Transactions>
```

Given above xml, let's say I want to modify for each transaction. I want to update id, time and date with some other values. Each transaction I will update with different data.

So I've been trying something like below:

```
NodeList transactions = doc.getElementsByTagName("Transaction");
for(int i = 0; i < transactions.getLength(); i++){
NodeList id = doc.getElementsByTagName("id");
//some method to update
modifyId(id)//this works but it is doing it for all IDs in Document
}
```

Above modify method does work and it does update after I do some Transforming and all, but it is updating all the transactions with same id,time,date values. I want to iterate through each "Transaction" and update its child nodes (id, time, date) separately, so they each will be different. How can this be done?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, since you apply the `getElementsByTagName` method to `doc` - the whole document - it gives you all the elements whose name is `id` in the entire document.

There are several solutions to this problem.

One is, when you traverse the `transaction` node list, use the `getChildNodes()` method to get its children. You can then use `getNodeName()` on each of them. Once you know the name of the element, you can do whatever you wanted with it.

```
for(int i = 0; i < transactions.getLength(); i++) {
    Node transaction = transactions.item(i);
    NodeList transactionChildren = transaction.getChildNodes();
    for ( int j = 0; j < transactionChildren.getLength(); j++ ) {
        Node elem = transactionChildren.item(j);
        switch ( elem.getNodeName() ) {
            case "id":
                // Whatever processing you want for id
                break;
            case "time":
                // Whatever processing you want for time
                break;
            case "date":
                // Whatever processing you want for date
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Another way is, when you traverse the `transaction` node list, to cast each node to an `Element` (the cast is supposed to succeed but you can always use `instanceof` to prevent the compiler from complaining). Then you can use the `getElementsByTagName(...)` method of *this particular element*. It should return a node list of only one item. Then you can do whatever you want with it.

```
for(int i = 0; i < transactions.getLength(); i++) {
    Node transactionNode = transactions.item(i);
    if ( transactionNode instanceof Element ) {
        transactionElem = (Element)transactionNode;
        NodeList elemList = transactionElem.getElementsByTagName("id");
        if ( elemList.getLength() >= 1 ) {
            Node idNode = elemList.item(0);
            // Do whatever you want with the id node
        }
        elemList = transactionElem.getElementsByTagName("date");
        if ( elemList.getLength() >= 1 ) {
            Node dateNode = elemList.item(0);
            // Do whatever you want with the date node
        }
        elemList = transactionElem.getElementsByTagName("time");
        if ( elemList.getLength() >= 1 ) {
            Node timeNode = elemList.item(0);
            // Do whatever you want with the time node
        }
    }
}
```